# Probability of two different players scoring a goal

Tags: probability

Bookmakers quite often price players to score a goal at any point during the game.

For example, they may give Ronaldo a 52% chance of scoring a goal in a game, and Messi a 60% chance of scoring a goal in a game.

However, how do you work out the possibility of either Messi or Ronaldo to score a goal in a game?

Comment: This reads like routine bookwork, such as could be set for exercises, assignments and so on. While you can ask such questions, they are treated differently. Please add the `self-study` tag, and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) which explains how to modify your question (including, showing what you've done already to solve this and identifying where, exactly, your difficulty lies).

Comment: Please expand your Q. Are they playing at same time or same team or both......

Answer (score 1):

Step 0.a: Set up some notation so we can talk less ambiguously. Let $R$ be the event "Rinaldo scores a goal in the game". Let $M$ be the event "Messi scores a goal in the game".

Step 0.b: Such questions require some assumption about the dependence between the two events. None has been given. How are the events $M$ and $R$ related? Is $P(M|R)=P(M|\bar{R})$, for example?

So far all we can do is apply elementary probability rules that will lead to (poor) bounds, or make some arbitrary assumption:

For two events $A$ and $B$,

$P(A \text{ or } B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(AB)$

Here $AB$ means $A \text{ and } B$

If we knew $A$ and $B$ were independent, we could then apply the rule $P(AB)=P(A)P(B)$ to simplify the expression, but there's nothing to indicate whether that's actually a sensible assumption (in this particular problem, if it were a real one, it might be an okay approximation).

Bounds:
In this case, $P(M \text{ or } R)$ must not exceed 1, and $P(MR)$ is smaller than both $P(M)$ and $P(R)$, so $P(MR)$ must be between $P(M)+P(R)-1$ and $\min(P(M),P(R))$, meaning that $0.12\leq P(MR)\leq 0.52$ and $0.6\leq P(M \text{ or } R) \leq 1$ ... which is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer below.  Just want to add that the question about R and M being independent can be resolved using historical data in a contingency table. Then apply the McNemar test of independence.

Comment: McNemar's test is not a test of independence. It is a test of marginal homogeneity. You may have meant the chi-squared test,

Answer (score -3):

If you add 52% and 60%, you get 112%. This is the percent of them that are likely to score a goal. When you average 52% and 60% you get 56%, which is the probability of one of them scoring a goal.

Comment: Probability is bounded above by 1. Let $R$ be the event Ronaldo scores and $M$ the event Messi scores. By summing them as you have, you have assumed they are mutually exclusive. Noting that $\text{Pr}(R)+\text{Pr}(M)>1$ should tell you immediately that they are not mutually exclusive i.e. $\text{Pr}(R\cap M)>0$. I don't know what you've done to average the two probabilities after that. That doesn't make sense.